# Generate numbers from n to m from a list

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'll start with an example; given n = 1 and m = 100 and a list [1, 2, 3]
generate all numbers with 1 digit and two digits and so on but they need to be less then 100 in this case.

Output:

`- 1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33`

Then we stop because the next numbers will over 100, e.g:

`- 111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 131, 132, 133, 21..,. 22..., 23..., 31, 32, 33`

As you noticed I am appending `1, 2, 3, 4` to a number created before, to do this I am using a recursive function, which is started in a for loop for each number in my list, and they it runs till the generated numbers are greater then my limit.

```
def x(str, finish, d, c) 
  return if d >= finish
  [1, 2, 3, 4].each do |e|
    x(str, end, d*c+e)
  end

  # do something if d >= str
end
```

This works fine if I need to start from 1, but if my starting number is a lot bigger, I still need to start to create this sequence.

Can somebody help me with a solution that will produce the same sequences, but from any starting point rather then 1, so if for example the starting point was 100 and end 200 the output will be:

`111, 112, 113, 114, 121, 122, 123, 124, 131, 132, 132 [...]`

A solution in any programming language would be nice, but please not builtin core libraries.

Comment: Which programming language did you use for that "pseudocode" ? Since you used a particular programming language, wouldn't tagging the question with it be a better approach to asking this question?

Comment: @Shark That's ruby.

Comment: In Ruby, `end` is a really awful variable name.

Comment: @avysk: No, it's not. Ruby uses keywords to delimit method definitions, not curly braces. And `end` is a reserved word.

Comment: What does "not builtin functions" mean? For example, Ruby doesn't have functions, only methods. Are we then allowed to use all methods from the core libraries since they are not functions?

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're right, I was not paying enough attention!

Comment: sorry for my mistakes, I corrected them, I don't use ruby that much this days, and that was meant to be as an example of the implementation that I had, I was not looking for a ruby specific solution, but someone suggested that I should add that the ruby tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed from "right" (least significant digit) to "left" (most significant digit), keeping track of two values:

- `min`, the least valid integer that has the same number of digits as what you've processed so far. So, for example, if you've processed a trailing `27`, then the least valid two-digit integer is `11`.
- `max`, the least valid integer that has the same number of digits as what you've processed so far *and* is greater than or equal to what you've processed so far. So, for example, if you've processed a trailing `27`, then the least valid two-digit integer greater than or equal to `27` is `31`.

  - Note that `max` won't always exist. For example, there's no valid two-digit integer greater than or equal to `70`.

The reason you need `min` is that if you encounter a digit that's not in your list of allowed digits, then the new `max` will incorporate the previous `min` instead of the previous `max`. (For example, the least valid two-digit integer greater than or equal to `02` is `11`, not `12`.)

At the end, you return `max`, if it exists; otherwise, you return `min`, but prepending the least digit from your list.

For example, if `this.allowedDigits` is a collection of allowed digits, then we can write (in Java):

```
private Integer getAllowedDigitGreaterThanOrEqualTo(final int digit) {
    for (int result = digit; result < 10; ++result) {
        if (this.allowedDigits.contains(result)) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    // digit is bigger than anything in the list:
    return null;
}

private int getAllowedNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(int n) {
    int minResult = 0;
    Integer maxResult = 0;
    int powerOfTen = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        final int digit = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        minResult = getAllowedDigitGreaterThanOrEqualTo(0) * powerOfTen + minResult;
        if (maxResult != null && this.allowedDigits.contains(digit)) {
            maxResult = digit * powerOfTen + maxResult;
        } else {
            final Integer newDigit = getAllowedDigitGreaterThanOrEqualTo(digit + 1);
            if (newDigit == null) {
                maxResult = null;
            } else {
                maxResult = newDigit * powerOfTen + minResult;
            }
        }
        powerOfTen *= 10;
    }
    if (maxResult == null) {
        return getAllowedDigitGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1) * powerOfTen + minResult;
    } else {
        return maxResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Code**

```
def generate_em(minimum, maximum, list)
  digits_min = minimum.to_s.size
  digits_min += 1 if minimum > (list.max.to_s*digits_min).to_i
  digits_max = maximum.to_s.size
  digits_max -= 1 if maximum < (list.min.to_s*digits_max).to_i
  (digits_min..digits_max).each_with_object([]) { |n,arr|
    arr.concat(list.repeated_permutation(n).to_a.map { |a| a.join.to_i }) }.
      uniq.
      select { |n| (minimum..maximum).cover?(n) }
end
```

**Examples**

*#1*

```
minimum =   1
maximum = 100
list = [1, 2, 3]

generate_em(minimum, maximum, list)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33]
```

*#2*

```
minimum = 78
maximum = 3332
list = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

generate_em(minimum, maximum, list)
  #=> [333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 353, 354, 355, 356,
  #    357, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 433, 434, 435,
  #    436, 437, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 463, 464,
  #    465, 466, 467, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 543,
  #    544, 545, 546, 547, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567,
  #    573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 643, 644, 645, 646,
  #    647, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 673, 674, 675,
  #    676, 677, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 743, 744, 745, 746, 747, 753, 754,
  #    755, 756, 757, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777]
```

*#3*

```
minimum = 0
maximum = 100
list = [0, 1, 2]

generate_em(minimum, maximum, list)
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 100]
```

**Explanation**

*Example #1*

The steps for the first example above are as follows.

```
digits_min = minimum.to_s.size
  #=> 1
```

Increase `digits_min` by one if `mimimum` is larger than the largest `digits_min` digits from `list`.

```
digits_min += 1 if minimum > (list.max.to_s*digits_min).to_i
digits_min
  #=> 1 

digits_max = maximum.to_s.size
  #=> 3
```

Decrease `digits_max` by one if `maximum` is smaller than the smallest `digits_max` digits from `list`.

```
digits_max -= 1 if maximum < (list.min.to_s*digits_max).to_i
digits_max
  #=> 2
```

We improve efficiency by having reduced `digits_max` from `3` to `2`

```
c = digits_min..digits_max
  #=> 1..2 
d = c.each_with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: 1..2:each_with_object([])>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by invoking [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries) (or [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a)) on it.

```
d.entries
  #=> [[1, []], [2, []]]

n, arr = d.next
  #=> [1, []] 
n #=> 1 
arr
  #=> [] 
e = list.permutation(n)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:permutation(2)>
f = e.to_a
  #=> [[1], [2], [3]] 
arr.concat f
  #=> [[1], [2], [3]] 
n, arr = d.next
  #=> [2, [[1], [2], [3]]] 
n #=> 2 
arr
  #=> [[1], [2], [3]] 
e = list.permutation(n)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:permutation(2)> 
f = e.to_a
  #=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]] 
arr.concat f
  #=> [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]
```

`arr` is returned by `each_with_object`'s block.

```
g = arr.map { |a| a.join.to_i }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32]
h = g.uniq
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32]
h.select { |n| (minimum..maximum).cover?(n) }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32]
```

*Example #2*

In the second example no two-digit combinations are generated because

```
78 > (list.max.to_s*2).to_i
  #=> 78 > 77 => true
```

and no four-digit combinations are generated because

```
3332 < (list.min.to_s*4).to_i
  #=> 3332 < 3333 => true
```

*Example #3*

Without `uniq`, the method would have returned duplicate values:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 100]
```

Comment: My answer is very similar to @Eric's earlier answer (though I didn't see his until I posted). The main difference is that I added an optimization to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Since you wrote your example code in Ruby, you could use [`repeated_permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) :

```
def possible_numbers(arr, min, max)
  min_digits = min.to_s.size
  max_digits = max.to_s.size
  (min_digits..max_digits).flat_map do |i|
    arr.repeated_permutation(i)
       .map { |digits| digits.join.to_i }
       .select { |number| number >= min && number <= max }
       .uniq
  end
end

p possible_numbers([1, 2, 3], 100, 200)
# => [111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 131, 132, 133]
```

Answer (score 2):

So, this takes an input of the digits provided, makes all the digit combinations repeatedly until it reaches your max. You'll want to adjust them to include recovery and saves in the event non-integers are entered or if it's otherwise impossible to hit the max for some reason - but this is a solid framework.

```
digits = [1,2,3]
max = 100

def possible_numbers(arr, max)
    loop do
      arr.product(arr).each do |combo| 
        return arr.uniq if combo.join("").to_i > max 
        arr << combo.join("").to_i
      end
    end
end

possible_numbers(digits, max)
```

Output:

```
=> [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33]
```

Comment: Nice use of [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-product). Note the question calls for a `min` value as well as a `max`